# When is a virtual column using AS rendered in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I wasn't sure how to search for the answer:

```
select orderid, REGEXP_REPLACE (
orderid, 
'^0+(.)',
'\1'
) as new_order_id
from orders 
where length('new_order_id') < 6
```

This returns nothing.  But I know the data is there.  If I do:

```
select orderid, REGEXP_REPLACE (
orderid, 
'^0+(.)',
'\1'
) as new_order_id
from orders 
order by order_id asc
```

I get order ids like 1, 2, 3...

So how can I get back the ones that are less than six?  Does the where not operation on my returned regexp_replace data after the dataset is returned.  Oracle if it matters.

Also, I believe my query is knocking out all leading zeros and replacing it with nothing.  Not sure what the \1 means.  Yes, I copied it.  I thought it was putting nothing there, which is what I want.  Just truncate leading zeros.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from
(select orderid
      , regexp_replace(orderid,'^0+(.)','\1') new_order_id
   from orders)
where length(new_order_id) < 6;
```

You can avoid using regexp:

```
select orderid
     , ltrim(orderid,'0') new_order_id
  from orders
 where length(ltrim(orderid,'0'))<6
 order by 1;
```

Comment: thank for the answer and the good query.  I made it harder than it was.

Answer (score 3):

In your query,

```
where length('new_order_id') < 6
```

compares the length of the literal string `'new_order_id'`, not the value of the field `new_order_id`.

Try removing the quotes:

```
where length(new_order_id) < 6
```

Comment: @johnny: You might have to spell out the `REGEXP_REPLACE(order_id, ...)` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I don't think it likes replace in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the string `'new_order_id'` is never less than 6. Probably you will have to do the `length(regexp_replace(...)) < 6` instead if oracle doesn't support using the output column name without quotes (I have no idea).